# Book identification: Book about an adolescent boy interested in WW2 memorabilia, wakes up in different time period.

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

A while ago (like 10+ years) I read a book that I can't remember the name of. See if you can help.

- Took place in Europe
- Main character was a boy preteen or teen...he was later joined by a girl around his age
- He was extremely interested in WW2 memorabilia
- Somehow he & the girl travel back in time & get to meet Elvis (I want to say they got in an old humvee with some crystals in it....)
- There was a bad guy, but I honestly don't remember what he was after... something the boy had that could bring him to his proper time (some sort of magic crystals I think...)
- He ended up blowing himself up somehow & waking up in his own time period.

I know this is very vague but it's been a while. I feel like the name is on the tip of my tongue but can't for the life of me remember it.

Comment: I don't know it, but something about the points you remember make it seem like something Stephen King might write.

Comment: It does sound like it could be Jimmy, but i know it's not Stephen king. The author came to our school & did a reading/signing for us (while that was cool, I grew up in a tiny country town who would have built a memorial for someone as famous as Stephen king coming to visit. Plus, they were a little too overly religious to have the master of horror stories come speak to the elementary school. Lol) I was in 4th or 5th grade... now that I think of it, it was much longer than 10 years ago Probably around 1996-1998.

Comment: @julia It looks like you have split accounts. You can go to the [Help Center](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and get them merged.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [*Conrad's War*](http://www5.scholastic.co.uk/zone/book_conrads-war.htm) by Andrew Davies?

I don't remember Elvis, or a girl, and it was more about WW2

> *Conrad loves everything about the guns. And the army. And war. Nobody in his family takes him seriously - until the night he smashes a tank
>   through the living room wall. Like it or not, Conrad's war is coming
>   to exciting, terrifying life... A book for boys of all ages.*

[image: Conrad's War]